# Using String.Format to build Regular Expressions: "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string.format

I'm bulding document-from-template engine. At certain points I need to match on Reg Exp groups and replace template text with content from a db.

I 'hardcoded' my RegExp initially, doing something like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"{DocSectionToggle::(?<ColumnName>\w+)::(?<ResponseValue>.+)}\n\[\[(?<SectionContent>.+)\]\]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

<sub>Apologies: it does group capture, so the syntax isn't the prettiest.</sub>

Just to make things neater and because I want' to keep the patterns in web.config or elsewhere, I've 'evolved' algorithm to something like:

```
string _regexp_DocSectionToggle = @"{DocSectionToggle::{0}::{1}}\n\[\[{2}\]\]";

/* Reg Exp Patterns for group capture */

string _rxCol            = @"(?<{ColumnName}>\w+)";
string _rxResp           = @"(?<{ResponseValue}>.+)";
string _rxSectContent    = @"(?<{SectionContent}>.+)"; 

Regex r = new Regex( string.Format(_regexp_DocSectionToggle,
                                    _rxCol,
                                    _rxResp,
                                    _rxSectContent), 

                      RegexOptions.Multiline
                   );
```

But I'm getting an error: 'Input string was not in correct format'.

Can anyone tell my why? Is this a limitation of `string.Format(...)`?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `{` and `}` which you *don't* want to mark format specifiers. IIRC, you just double them:

```
string _regexp_DocSectionToggle = @"{{DocSectionToggle::{0}::{1}}}\n\[\[{2}\]\]";
```

Comment: Hurrah. Another John Skeet supplied answer just for me and my question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `{` and `}` by using `{{` and `}}` as the following:

```
string _regexp_DocSectionToggle = @"{{DocSectionToggle::{0}::{1}}}\n\[\[{2}\]\]";
```